# when i right click in MS excel sheet , options like cut , delete insert are not shown and i am not able add delete any raw, column

Tags: microsoft-excel

i have some operating issue in using MS office
when i work in MS office  in excel i need to add /delete /insert raw and column but
when i right click in MS excel sheet , options like cut , delete insert are not shown and i am not able add delete any raw and  column
i have following
i have gone to option > advance >cut,copy,paste>
selected all and okayed it after that i reboot my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue occur with all Excel workbooks? Please check this issue in a new created blank worksheet.

1.If the issue occurs with specific files, please go to File > Info > Protect Workbook, chcek whether "**Protect Workbook Structure**" is enabled.

Please also press Alt+F11 to open VB Editor,check whether the macro code altered the menu. Or you could click `View>Immediate Window` > Enter "**Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset**" > Press Alt+Q to return to worksheet and this issue.

2.If the issue occurs with all excel files, please go to `File > Optons > Add-ins > Manage, COM Add-ins/ Excel Add-ins > Go`, uncheck these add-ins to narrow down this issue.

In addition, go to `C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`, move the files temporarily to prevent any configurations rebuilt Excel after starting Excel.